# How can I stop code from being run in the compiler phase?

Tags: perl, constants

This question requires an understanding of compiler phase, vs  the `BEGIN` block. From *Programming Perl: 3rd Edition - Page 467*

> It's also important to understand the distinction between compile phase and compile time, and between run phase and run time. A typical Perl program gets one compile phase, and then one run phase. A "phase" is a large-scale concept. But compile time and run time are small-scale concepts. A given compile phase does mostly compile-time stuff, but it also does some run-time stuff via `BEGIN` blocks. A given run phase does mostly run-time stuff, but it can do compile-time stuff through operators like `eval STRING`.

Let's take very a simple example

```
sub complex_sub {
  die 'code run';
}
sleep 5;
print 'good';
use constant FOO => complex_sub();
```

if the above is run as-is, then `complex_sub` from the users perspective is run in the compiler phase. However, with slight modifications I can have..

```
# Bar.pm
package Bar {
  use constant FOO => main::complex_sub();
}

# test.pl
package main {
  sub complex_sub {
    die 'code run';
  }
  sleep 5;
  print 'good';
  require Bar;
}
```

In the above code `complex_sub` is run in the execution phase. Is there anyway to differentiate these two cases from the perspective of `complex_sub` to enable the top syntax, but to prohibit the bottom syntax.

Comment: Is it really run at run time? Shouldn't it switch from run time to compile time at the point of `require`, where it loads the file and then parses it, running compile time stuff, which will pick up the `use constant`, before then switching back to run time and running the contents of the file.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the `${^GLOBAL_PHASE}` variable. It contains "START" in the first case, but "RUN" in the second one.

```
# RUN
perl -wE'say ${^GLOBAL_PHASE}'

# START
perl -wE'BEGIN {say ${^GLOBAL_PHASE}}'

# RUN
perl -wE'eval q{BEGIN {say ${^GLOBAL_PHASE}}}'
```

See [perlvar](http://p3rl.org/perlvar) for details.

Comment: For posterity, this is only the correct solution when you actually want to know (like the variable name says) which *global* phase you are in, regardless of whether the current code unit is being parsed/compiled or run. In other words, the only things that happen in the global START phase are parsing the top level script unit and the parsing and runtime phases of any `use`d modules or `BEGIN` blocks in that top level unit - mostly the same things that happen when executing the script with `-c`.

Comment: And it's important to note [${^GLOBAL_PHASE}](https://perldoc.pl/variables/$%7B%5EGLOBAL_PHASE%7D) was added in 5.14.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use Const::Fast;

sub complex_sub {
  die 'code run';
}

sleep 5;
print 'good';

const my $FOO => complex_sub();
```

Which outputs:

```sh
<5 second pause>
code run at /tmp/so1.pl line 6.
good
```

This works because though the lexical variable is declared at compile time it isn't set till run time.

Comment: You can also do this by deconstructing the `use constant` into a runtime expression: `require constant; constant->import(FOO => complex_sub);` - this will (like the deferred example in the OP) prevent `FOO` from resolving as a symbol without parentheses, since the parser will not be aware of it.